# How to avoid going to another page while pulling to refresh

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

Here is my problem: I have a page which contains a `<ion-refresher>`and several `<app-ad-cell>`.

```html
<div>
  <app-ad-cell *ngFor="let ad of ads" [ad]="ad" [routerLink]="['.', ad.id]"></app-ad-cell>
</div>
```

When I pull to refresh whereas I began the movement on a cell, my app refreshes the list **AND** go to the page (because of the `routerLink`.

How do I do if I want to only refresh my list, even if the movement began on a cell ?

[SEE WHAT IS HAPPENING](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6jG4.jpg)

## EDIT 1

If tested on browser and on *Android* for the moment and this problem only appears on the browser